# How can I change the default input radix to hexadecimal in Radare2?

Tags: radare2

Frequently when I use Radare2 I work mostly in hexadecimal. This means I'm constantly having to remember to type `0x` in front of addresses, which is different from the machine-language monitors I'm used to using. (I'm generally working with binaries for 8-bit systems, where decimal is rarely used when working in machine language.)

Is there any way to set the default input radix to hexadecimal? I'd like to be able to type `s ff00` instead of `s 0xff00` at the command line, and `gff00` instead of `g0xff00` in visual mode.

And if I can do this, how does one enter decimal numbers, should that be necessary, in this mode?

Links to documentation are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is no such option currently in radare2 (though more experienced radare2 contributors would tell it for sure).

However, if you are really annoyed by having to type `0x`'s in front every single time, you can perform a *temporary* (very hacky) solution. To do so, you can modify the `libr/core/cmd_seek.c` file (which is responsible for handling seek command) as follows:
[image: r2SeekHAck]

And then use `make` to compile the project. After this, you will get the feature you want (will also work with `g` in Visual Mode):

[image: r2HexSeekHack]

You can find the patch code below:

```
ut64 addr;
if ((input[1] >= '1' && input[1] <= '9') || (input[1] >= 'a' && input[1] <= 'f'))
{
    char inputHex[strlen(input) + 1];
    inputHex[0] = '0';
    inputHex[1] = 'x';
    int i = 2;
    for (; i < strlen(input) + 1; i++)
        inputHex[i] = input[i - 1];
    addr = r_num_math (core->num, inputHex);
} 
else
     addr = r_num_math (core->num, input + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

i cant say how much helpful this is but you can set e asm.tailsub=true and use .. instead of 0x
(this is not actually replacing the 0x it is tail substitution)

that is it will seek to +0x10 if you do s .. 10 from current seek 
or seek 0x100 if you do s ..100 or seek 0x1000 if you do s ..1000

it only substitutes the tail we are abusing this by substituting the whole body see the edit just so if you were wondering how are why

like

```
radare2 c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe
 -- Enable asm.trace to see the tracing information inside the disassembly
[0x140001820]> e asm.tailsub
false
[0x140001820]> s 1400018f0
Cannot seek to unknown address '1400018f0'
[0x140001820]> e asm.tailsub = true
[0x140001820]> s ..1400018f0
[0x1400018f0]>
```

edit as explanation for what is .. or tailsub

[0x100000000]

```
> s entry0
[0x140001820]> s ..1337
[0x140001337]> s ..99999
[0x140099999]>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to the documentation on `asm.tailsub`? I'm not entirely clear on exactly how it works, and a search of the Radare2 book provides no results for "tailsub." It does look like it might be useful beyond just allowing me to default to hex radix.

Comment: `asm.tailsub` doesn't seem strictly related to the `..` syntax. I've conformed with `e asm.tailsub` that it's `false` and yet I can use commands such as `s ..c000` (which seeks to 0xc000 on  a freshly opened file) and `omb. ..c000` (which sets the offset to 0x0c000, sometimes).

Comment: ok ive seen it acting weird  try s someaddr+..f0 it willseek to  double the current seek but such is the nature of features that arent production tested